# XCtest based testcase causing NSStream callback not to fire

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, testing, xctest

I have a simple app that opens a NSStream connection to a server on pressing a button, this works fine as a normal IOS app with a connected Iphone device.
When I use XCTest for a unit test I don't get any data transfer over the NSStream connection.

I see the following at the beginning of my App under XCTest framework

```
2014-07-25 09:35:51.013 GolgiBird[33407:60b] Unable to get entitlements for client task. Error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=-1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (POSIX error -1 - Unknown error: -1)"
2014-07-25 09:35:51.020 GolgiBird[33407:60b] Unable to get entitlements for client task. Error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=-1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (POSIX error -1 - Unknown error: -1)"
```

I am using XCode 5.1, IOS 7.1, IPHone 5S

Anyone have an idea what might be going on here, The above errors might not be the cause of the NSStream problem but rather something in the XCTest framework itself

So basically the callback

```
(void)stream:(NSStream *)stream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent
{
...
}
```

is not been called under the XCTest framework